# How to use ng-repeat for array of objects and bind it to checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display a checkbox inside Cards. So whenever the checkbox is checked the value is going to bind. It is working fine. But I need to do this for many cards. Instead of repeating the same code, I need to know the better way to achieve it. I saw many of the solutions related to this but no use.

**Controller code**

```
$scope.carBrand = {
    "carbrands" : {
        "BMW" : [ 
            {
                "d320" : $scope.bmwPermission.d320,
                "note" : "Users who likes d320 ",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "d520" : $scope.bmwPermission.d520,
                "note" : "Users who likes d520",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "d720" :$scope.bmwPermission.d720,
                "note" : "Users who likes d720",
                "configurable" : true
            }
        ],
        "AUDI" : [ 
            {
                "A1" :  $scope.audiPermission.A1,
                "note" : "Users who likes A1",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "A2" : $scope.audiPermission.A2,
                "note" : "Users who likes A2",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "A3" : $scope.audiPermission.A3,
                "note" : "Users who likes A3",
                "configurable" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
$scope.bmwDependencyCheck = function(newObj) {
    if( $scope.bmwPermission.d320){
        $scope.bmwPermission.d520 = true
        $scope.bmwPermission.d720 = true            
    }else if ($scope.bmwPermission.d520){
        $scope.bmwPermission.d720 = true
    }
 }


...
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<pre>

<div class="card inline  col-md-3">
  <div class="card-heading">
    <div class="content-block lead inline col-md-12" >
      <label class="col-md-8 text-align-left"> BMW </label>
     </div>
    </div>                                                                                                                                      
    <div class="card-body">
       <ul class="flexview lbl-content">
         <li class="lable col-md-10">
          <label class="checkbox-inline" for="bmw-d320">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chpview" id="bmw-d320"
                   ng-model="bmwPermission.d320"         
                   ng-change="bmwDependencyCheck(bmwPermission.d320)" />d320
           </label>
         </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="flexview lbl-content">
        <li class="lable col-md-10">
          <label class="checkbox-inline" for="bmw-d520">
           <input type="checkbox" name="chpview" id="bmw-d520"
                  ng-model="bmwPermission.d520"                                                                 
                  ng-change="bmwDependencyCheck(bmwPermission.d520)" />d520                                                           
           </label>
        </li>
       </ul>
     .
     .
     .

  </div>            
</div>  
</pre>
```

Comment: Too much unnecessary code. Please better format your question, What variables will be binded to checkboxes? What is the array? Could you remove everything redundant from example and just leave some tiny clear code?

Comment: Hi,
This can be solved by using two ng-repeat.
The model needs to be as below,
CarBrands[ {BrandName: "BMW",Models: []},
   {BrandName: "AUDI",Models: []}]
Further, the first ng-repeat needs to be on CarBrands array (every instance is an item) and second ng-repeat on item.Models

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you meant this working model. As said @Santhosh_mp you need to use two ng-repeat.

Note, the value binding will be on unique keys...

in your case you need to create a model key for each and every row and check whether it exists, so the key reference is same on all loop

```
 {
            "d320" : $scope.bmwPermission.d320,
             "model": "d320"
            "note" : "Users who likes d320 ",
            "configurable" : true
        }, 
<input ng-if="row.model === 'd320'" type="checkbox" ng-model="row.d320">
```

This method requires multiple checkboxes with ng-if.....and cannot work dynamic.. Say for example adding d321 will need to be coded again.

So instead i changed the key to **value** instead of d320

I am not sure, why the ng-model for the second ng-repeat did not bind bind... So i made a seperate function and called it at initialize and on every model change

```
<div ng-controller="CarsController">
  <ul class="flexview lbl-content">
         <li class="lable col-md-10">
          <label class="checkbox-inline" for="bmw-d320">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chpview" id="bmw-d320"
                   ng-model="bmwPermission.d320"         
                   ng-change="bmwDependencyCheck(bmwPermission.d320)" />d320
           </label>
         </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="flexview lbl-content">
        <li class="lable col-md-10">
          <label class="checkbox-inline" for="bmw-d520">
           <input type="checkbox" name="chpview" id="bmw-d520"
                  ng-model="bmwPermission.d520"                                                                 
                  ng-change="bmwDependencyCheck(bmwPermission.d520)" />d520                                                           
           </label>
        </li>
       </ul>

       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="(key, values) in carBrand.carbrands">{{key}}
           <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="row in values">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.value">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;{{row.note}}
               &nbsp;&nbsp;{{row.configurable}}
             </li>
           </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app  = angular.module('stackoverflow', []);
app.controller('CarsController', function($scope, $timeout){
$scope.bmwPermission={};
$scope.audiPermission={};
$scope.bmwPermission.d320 = false;
$scope.bmwPermission.d520 = false;
$scope.bmwPermission.d720 = false;
$scope.audiPermission.A1 = false;
$scope.audiPermission.A2 = false;
$scope.audiPermission.A3 = false;

$scope.defineCars = function(){
$scope.carBrand = {
    "carbrands" : {
        "BMW" : [ 
            {
                "value" : $scope.bmwPermission.d320,
                "note" : "Users who likes d320 ",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "value" : $scope.bmwPermission.d520,
                  "note" : "Users who likes d520",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "value" :$scope.bmwPermission.d720,
                "note" : "Users who likes d720",
                "configurable" : true
            }
        ],
        "AUDI" : [ 
            {
                "value" :  $scope.audiPermission.A1,
                "note" : "Users who likes A1",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "value" : $scope.audiPermission.A2,
                "note" : "Users who likes A2",
                "configurable" : true
            }, 
            {
                "value" : $scope.audiPermission.A3,
                "note" : "Users who likes A3",
                "configurable" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}
}

$scope.bmwDependencyCheck = function(newObj) {

 if( $scope.bmwPermission.d320){
        $scope.bmwPermission.d520 = true
        $scope.bmwPermission.d720 = true            
    }else if ($scope.bmwPermission.d520){
        $scope.bmwPermission.d720 = true
    }


$scope.defineCars();    
 }
$scope.defineCars(); 
});
```

[The working jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/3kpfz1q4/1/)

Comment: Thank you soo much.                                                                                                                                But I don't have the luxury to change the structure. So can I do anything with the "index" by keeping the same KEY and update it whenever it is checked